# Start date and end date assigning based on date ranges and value change

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables temp_N and temp_C . Table script and data is given below . I am using teradata
[Table Script and data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/966692/3)
First image is temp_N and second one is temp_C

[image: Temp_N]

[image: Temp_C]

Now I will try to explain my requirement. Key column for this two tables are 'nbr'. This two table contains all the changes for a particular period of time.( this is sample data and this two tables will get daily loaded based on the updates). Now I need to merge this two tables into one table with date range assigned correctly. The expected result is given below. To explain the logic behind the expected result, first row in the expected result, fstrtdate is the least date which from the two tables which is 2022-01-31 and for the same row if we notice the end date is given as 2022-07-10 as there is a change in the cpnrate on 2022-07-11. second row is start with 2022-07-11 giving the changed cpnrate, now when comes to third row there is a change in ntr on 2022-08-31 and the data is update accordingly. Please note all this are date fields, there wont be any timestamp,  please ignore the timestamp in screenshots

[image]

Now I would like to know how to achieve this in sql or is it possible to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine all the changes into a single table and order by effective start date (fstrtdate). Then you can compute effective end date as day prior to next change, and where one of the data values is NULL use LAG IGNORE NULLS to "bring down" the desired previous not-NULL value:

```
SELECT nbr, fstrtdate, 
  PRIOR(LEAD(fstrtdate) OVER (PARTITION BY nbr ORDER BY fstrtdate)) as fenddate,
  COALESCE(ntr,LAG(ntr) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY nbr ORDER BY fstrtdate)) as ntr,
  COALESCE(cpnrate,LAG(cpnrate) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY nbr ORDER BY fstrtdate)) as cpnrate
FROM (
   SELECT nbr, fstrtdate, max(ntr) as ntr, max(cpnrate) as cpnrate
   FROM (
        SELECT  nbr, fstrtdate, ntr, NULL (DECIMAL(9,2)) as cpnrate 
        from    temp_n
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  nbr, fstrtdate, NULL (DECIMAL(9,2)) as ntr, cpnrate 
        from    temp_c
        ) AS COMBINED
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    ) AS UNIQUESTART
ORDER BY fstrtdate;
```

The innermost SELECTs make the structure the same for data from both tables with NULLs for the values that come from the other table, so we can do a UNION to form one COMBINED derived table with rows for both types of change events.  Note that you should explicitly assign datatype for those added NULL columns to match the datatype for the corresponding column in the other table; I somewhat arbitrarily chose DECIMAL(9,2) above since I didn't know the real data types. They can't be INT as in the example, though, since that would truncate the decimal part. There's no reason to carry along the original fenddate; a new non-overlapping fenddate will be computed in the outer query.

The intermediate GROUP BY is only to combine what would otherwise be two rows in the special case where both ntr and cpnrate changed on the same day for the same nbr. That case is not present in the example data - the dates are already unique - but it might be necessary to do this when processing the full table. The syntax requires an aggregate function, but there should be at most two rows for a (nbr, fstrtdate) group; and when there are two rows, in each of the other columns one row has NULL and the other row does not. In that case either MIN or MAX will return the non-NULL value.

In the outer query, the COALESCEs will return the value for that column from the current row in the UNIQUED derived table if it's not NULL, otherwise LAG is used to obtain the value from a previous row.

The first two rows in the result won't match the screenshot above but they do accurately reflect the data provided - specifically, the example does not identify a cpnrate for any date prior to 2022-05-11.

| nbr | fstrtdate | fenddate | ntr | cpnrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 233 | 2022-01-31 | 2022-05-10 | 311,000.00 | NuLL |
| 233 | 2022-05-11 | 2022-07-10 | 311,000.00 | 3.31 |
| ... | - | - | - | - |

Comment: Thank you.. I will try it out this with different data I have.. Also I will try to understand the query logic , like how exactly it works.. One thing which I noticed is that the logic is build based on the ntr and cpnrate by taking max..but its not always the case, some times the latest change value will be less than the earlier value, in that case I guess it will not work as expected

Comment: I will try it out and keep posted here

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a more comprehensive explanation.